# where does the downloaded file gets stored in the R-Studio Server on Ubuntu EC2 Instance when using download.file()

Tags: r, rstudio

Studio Server on an Ubuntu EC2 instance for the first time and successfully started r-studio server in my browser. I also have putty ssh client.For the Purpose of this Analysis i first want to download a file from the Website called UCI Machine Learning Repository and then access the file for downstream Analysis, so i used the Below shown R Script in the r-studio server in my browser

```
download.file("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/haberman/haberman.data", destfile = "Haberman.txt")
```

This works exactly fine but since i am new to work in the Cloud Platform i couldn't understand where RStudio stores the Haberman.txt file, because when i work on my PC i used to specify the Path to store the Haberman.txt file in the destfile argument as shown below

```
 download.file("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/haberman/haberman.data", destfile = "E:/Couresera_Datasets/Haberman.txt")
```

Now when i Navigate to the specified Path in my PC i will be able to find the Haberman.txt file but where can i find the Haberman.txt file in the Ubuntu EC2 instance when i use the download.file()?

Any Help Will be Appreciated.

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 1):

It'll put it exactly where you asked for it:

```
 destfile = "Haberman.txt"
```

that is, a file called `Haberman.txt` in the current working directory at the time you ran `download.file`. You can get the current working directory with `getwd()` in R.

So for example if its something you can read with `read.csv`, you can do:

```
hdata = read.csv("Haberman.txt")
```

as long as you haven't changed the current working directory (like with `setwd`).